# Small Signal Pi Model Current Mirror

Tags: signal, bjt, current-source, current-mirror

[image]

The issue I'm having is with Part C. I've rewritten the circuit with the Pi model as such:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get an iout/i relationship. I can only think of writing the current laws, but it doesn't seem to get me anywhere to where I can write the ratio. Since the top of r0 and bottom of r0 is grounded, I think no current can run through it, so it does nothing.

Comment: How does a current mirror work ? The current is converted into a Vbe by Q1, then Q2 turns this voltage back into a current again. Reflect the same in your small signal model. Your bottom circuit is correct but Bib (Beta*iB) for the two controlled sources in the middle is **nonsense**. Look up the proper equations for the small signal model ! Then the voltage controlling the right controlled current source will be the voltage across the left source.

Comment: The question involves both DC and AC/small-signal modeling. AC modeling lets you extract stiffness/compliance at a particular I/V bias point for the transistors collectors. DC modeling lets you determine current-ratio, and thus Iout of the mirroring device.